# pathForResource returns null

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm trying to load some .applescript files in my project.

Copied them into the "Supporting Files" directory like this:

[image]

and tried to access them:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSLog(@"Resource path for test.applescript: %@", [bundle pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"applescript"]);
```

pathForResource always returns null.

Both files are correctly imported in xcode. The target membership is my app.
Solutions from similar questions didn't really help

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

In the Xcode target "Build Phases" add the file under "Copy Bundle Resources"".

Comment: Drag/drop is still broken in Xcode 4.5 :( - e.g. dragging Apple's own OpenGL shaders from Finder to a project failed to add them to the Copy Bundle Resources phase (why? surely this isn't difficult for Apple to implement!). Sigh.

Comment: I had the same issue, but files have already been added to Copy Bundle Resources stage, so that was not the issue. What I had to do (however weird this is, and points probably to an error in my current Xcode IDE) was moving these respective files from a project Group (Folder) to the root of project (Xcode 5.1.1). Sic!

Comment: OMG took me twenty minutes to figure out where to click. Wish I could add an screenshot for you.

Comment: Email it to me and I will add it.

Comment: Thank you for saving me! I am using Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18). 10 years after you posted the answer.

Answer (score 5):

For all those who are still getting a nil path and the file is added in "Copy Bundle Resources" just remove the file from Copy Bundle Resources and than add again.

Answer (score 1):

Great response from Zaph above, but I noticed when I was doing it there's quicker way, at least in Xcode 6.1.

if you single click the file (eg. test.applescript) and have the right menu of Xcode open, you'll see a section called "Target Membership". Make sure that the right target (as in the one you're using the script with) is selected and it'll do the same job as adding the file under "Copy Bundle Resources"

Also, not entirely relevant but in case you're loading from several different places, or you are inheriting this class. You shouldn't really use

[NSBundle mainBundle];

instead use

```
[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
```

That means you don't have to worry about where you are on the method call it'll take the resource from the appropriate items associated with the target you're running. Great for making libraries and reusable calls ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does your image assume that that file in some folder?

Try `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:` method in this case:

```
NSLog(@"Resource path for test.applescript: %@", [bundle pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"applescript" inDirectory:@"folder/Supporting Files");
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Zaph said, be sure that you are not running in 'Release' mode.

There was a time where I forgot to change that setting back, and the symbols were stripped, thus making NSBundle incapable of resolving the path.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have this issue on the app start, note that [bundle pathForResource] will not work earlier than in the applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Update: Also, make sure you are running it from the main thread.