# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation

I am just putting in sound effects for my game, which was working well until I put in this code:

```
if (hit == NO) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"miss" ofType:@"m4a"];
        AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        [theAudio play];
        NSLog(@"audio played miss.m4a");
        // if hit is no miss sound effect plays

    }
    else {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hit" ofType:@"m4a"];
        AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        [theAudio play];
        NSLog(@"audio played hit.m4a");
        //if hit is yes or else (not no) then it plays hit sound effect
    }
```

It says the problem is around the [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] part and I have examined it and gone over many questions and tutorials but can't seem to find a solution. All of my files are in the Xcode project and are named correctly and correspond to my pathForResource:@"miss" and hit and the ofType etc.

Comment: Are your files present in "Copy Bundle Resources" in `Build Phases`?

Comment: Perhaps you haven't added the files to "Copy Bundle Resources": http://stackoverflow.com/a/9332075/2274694

Comment: yes i had added it to the folder above copy bundle resources thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the path using a breakpoint, if it is nil probably the resource is not in the bundle or it is with a different name.
Pay attention that while the simulator is case insensitive, the device is case sensitive.

Comment: This is another problem, you should post another question. Are you sure that the device is not in silent mode?